# PHP read text files very slowly

Tags: php, lamp, file-read

I have a large number of files in a directory and I'm using php to read it to a string. For example, a file's path looks like this: `filerootdir/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/file.txt`.

I have a million such txt files. Based on different parameter, php will read the txt file and display it as a part of the webpage. I'm testing the php program on Windows 7 Pro right now. When a file's absolute path is short, e.g., `filerootdir/dir1/file.txt`, it's pretty fast to load. But when the absolute path is long, it is VERY slow. I'm wondering if there is a better solution for this problem.

I'm testing my program under windows WAMP, but it will be moved to LAMP later eventually. Will the file loading program fun faster on linux servers? Could this be a problem of Windows operating system?

The code I'm using looks like the following:

```
if (file_exists($filePath.".html")) {
        $code = file_get_contents($filePath.".html");
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Show us codes and we might tell.

Comment: as a guess: switch off any antivirus software for test (if you have any installed)

Comment: I would not expect that to run slowly. What happens when you run `type filerootdir/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/file.txt` at the command prompt? Is that slow as well? What about if you do the same code, but with a completely different path? Are there millions of files in that directory, or are they spread over many directories?

Comment: @AMADANONInc. It is not slow when I type command. I have 5000 directorys under filerootdir/, some contain thousands of files, some contain only a few. 
+update thanks for your comment. I just test several different pages again. It seems that when a directory contains more file, it is slow, when it contains less it it faster. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Is changing the directory structure out of the question?

Comment: @mopo922 the directory hierarchy is being used(shown to user), can not change.

Comment: I know that Linux has a certain number of files per directory; if you go over that number, any access of that directory slows down lot.

Comment: @AMADANONInc. Very interesting! What is the magic number? approximately?

Comment: I don't know - I had a google, but couldn't find anything specific.

Comment: I don't think the path will cause a much difference... probably you could check whether the no of files in the longer path are same as in the shorter path. Maybe the no of files in the longer path are too many... and the shorter path has only a few files to handle. ..Also is there any other code being used by you.. other than above...

Comment: It seems to depend largely on your filesystem - ext3 (and ext4) have huge improvements over the (dated) ext2, an option called dir_index (don't know if this is default) seems to fix this problem - at least up to 1 million directory entries (per directory).

Comment: @NinadAjnikar I think you are right, the number of the files in the  directory affects the load time a lot, not the length of the path. The length of path just correlates with the number of files. So when the number is large, it should be slow, any solution for this?

Comment: For 500,000 files on BTRFS, `ls -f|wc -l` (which reads the entire directory, but doesn't display it) takes .4 seconds, sorted this takes 7 seconds. cat (the equivalent of type) takes .001 seconds. The directory itself (not the files in it) takes up 6.4mb.

Comment: @Ryan: I cant think of a solution probably the simplest will be store the files evenly in folders .. so after 1000 files are stored the next one should get stored in a diff folder...also I think this is then going to be OS dependent and not PHP so you can try your luck by setting up a LAMP environment locally!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider storing the data in a database - if you are using this number of records, especially if they are small files, a database will probably be more efficient. Before you do, read up on indexes - they can grab the right record out of billions in a tiny fraction of a second.

Comment: Absolutely an option if no solution for using directories.